# SQL Server Database Design - Seperate Table for Sale and Purchase

Tags: sql-server, database-design, data-structures

I am building a new business application for my personal business which has close   to ~100 transactions of sale and purchase per day. I am thinking of having Separate tables to record the sale and purchase with another linked table for Items that were sold and a seperate linked table with items that were purchased.

```
Example:
**SaleTable**
InvoiceNo
TotalAmt

**SaleTableDetail**
LinkedInvNo
ProductID
Quantity
Amount
etc.,
```

would this design be better or would it be more efficient to have one transactiontable with a column stating sale or purchase?
-From an App/Database/Query/Reporting Perspective

Comment: Isn't it better just to change order status? Ordered/Dispatched/Paid/Delivered ...

Comment: Agreed but I'm thinking when pulling it into a query and from a general storage perspective as well as from writing code on the front end app. What would be the best way to store data. As we would often need to pull prices to arrive at profitability. Generate tax reports etc.,

Comment: You can create order_history table where you can trace all your status changes. In my opinion it is more flexible. From perspective of the writing code, there is no difference what table to join "sale" or "order_history"

Answer (score 2):

1. An invoice is not the same as a sales order. An invoice is a request for payment. A sales order is an agreement to sell products to a party at a price on a date.
2. A sales order is almost exactly the same as a purchase order, except you are the customer, and a sales order line item can reference a purchase order line item. You can put them in separate tables, but you should probably use Table Inheritance (CTI, extending from an abstract Order). Putting them in the same table with a "type" column is called Single Table Inheritance and is nice and simple.
3. Don't store totals in your operational db. You can put them in your analytic db though (warehouse).

Comment: Hi Neil Thank you very much for that information. I have decided to go with one table. You raised another very interesting point about operational vs analytics db. I am not familiar with that concept. Please can you elaborate?

Answer (score 1):

You are starting small, thats a quick way to do. But, I am sure, very shortly you will run into differences between sale and purchase transactions, some fields will describe only a sale and some fields that will be applicable only for purchases.

In due course, you may want to keep track of modifications or a modification audit. Then you start having multiple rows for the same transaction with fields indicating obsoletion or you have to move history records to another table.

Also, consider the code-style-overhead in all your queries, you got to mention the Transaction Type as sale or purchase for simple queries.

It would be better to design your database with a model that maps business reality closest. At the highest level, everything may abstract to a "transaction", with date, amount and some kind of tag to indicate amount is paid or received against what context. That shouldn't mean we can have a table with Tag, Date, Amount, PayOrReceive to handle all the diverse transactions.

Comment: Hi whirl wind thank you for the additional input unfortunately I'm more confused now I would have abt 100 txn per day and I think the information required I my biz for sale and purchase would be similar to large extent